# What is American English for "cross-party"?

Tags: american-english, vocabulary

I came across the word 'cross-party' while reading the newspaper. I didn't know this word so I looked it up in a dictionary. (Denoting interaction between two or more political parties).

I noticed that I didn't find this word in an AmE dictionary, it only seems to exist in BrE. I have done an advanced search in google and it is almost never used on CNN (3.000  results in 0,46 sec), but BBC seems to use it quite often (45000 results in 0,46 sec).

Now my question is next: Is there a synonym for this word in AmE?

Comment: Cynically, no: could the Republicans and Democrats ever manage to work together to necessitate such a word?

Comment: 'bipartisan' (from two parties) is what is used in the US.

Comment: 'Bipartisan' is the common single word, and I think you will also find the phrase "across party lines" used often.

Comment: @Zeya Van Noten Is it an AmEng equivalent to use in he specific context of US politics that you're after?

Answer (score 27):

In the US, the term **bipartisan** is often used, as most politicians identify with either the Republican or the Democratic party.  This is opposed to, for example, the UK, where it is sometimes said that there are two-and-half parties, with the Liberal Democrats, Labour, and Conservative party.

EDIT:  Additionally, as pointed out in the comments, the Scottish National Party is now the third largest party in the Commons.

[According to the OD](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/cross-party)

> the term cross-party does not compete very effectively with the
>   default term bipartisan

So, as a simple answer to your question, no, there is not a simple, widely used term, as the government in America is still mostly divided in two (which makes **bipartisan** the easy and most effective term to describe the dichotomic nature of American politics.

Comment: I would add that the two-party system is so ingrained in the American system that *bipartisan* is often used even when there are third parties or independents in the mix, since the overwhelming majority of participants in any such project, bill, panel, etc. will be from the two major parties. In other words, a commission of four Democrats, three Republicans, and one Libertarian is still a *bipartisan* commission.

Comment: I think the term would be understood by intelligent people if expanded using Latin number prefixes, e.g. tripartisan, quadripartisan, quintipartisan.

Comment: A couple of corrections: the party you're referring to as the "half" is the [Liberal Democrats](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liberal_Democrats), which is not the same as the [Liberal Party](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liberal_Party_%28UK,_1989%29), the former having 8 seats in the Commons, and the latter having none. Also, as of 2015, the third largest party in the Commons is the Scottish National Party.

Comment: @choster: Indeed. And conversely, a commission with no Democrats, or with no Republicans, probably *wouldn't* be called "bipartisan", even if it did contain a member of a third party.

Answer (score 11):

[Cross-party](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/cross-party?q=cross+party) means:

> Involving or relating to ***two or more political parties***: a cross-party
>   committee of MPs.

In the UK political system, there are [multiple parties](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_political_parties_in_the_United_Kingdom), 11 of which have Members of Parliament, UK House of Commons. This might be the reason why "cross-party" is used in the U.K.

[Wikipedia]

However, in the US political system, there have been only 2 ***major*** parties in its recent history, the Republican Party and Democratic Party. There were some small parties, but they were not strong enough to exert any influence on policy-making. In the House of Representatives, only two major parties are holding seats. That's why [bipartisan](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/bipartisan) is used in the U.S. which means:

> Of or involving the agreement or cooperation of ***two political parties***
>   that usually oppose each other’s policies: the reforms received
>   considerable bipartisan approval

[Oxford Online Dictionary]

Comment: Which two parties are the major ones has changed through US history.  The Federalists, the Democrat-Republicans, and the Whigs have all had presidents elected. We've had 150 years of the Democrat / Republican divide. Fix that, and your answer will be clearer.

Comment: @jejorda2 I have edited my answer to "in its ***recent***" history" which is better. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: -1 This has nothing to do with there currently being 11 parties with MPs in the UK. "Cross-party" is often used to mean "both of the major parties".

Comment: (Although your answer may be correct in terms of the US equivalent being "bipartisan", I object to the large amount of misinformation in your answer).

Comment: @AndyT Where did I say cross-party means ***only*** between two parties? What is the large amount of misinformation? That's just part of explanations. If you could post better answer, go ahead.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/31758/discussion-between-andyt-and-rathony).

Comment: @Rathony - I'm not sure what you mean by "Your downvote means nothing to me. Got it?". My downvote is not an attack on you, it is me registering my opinion as to whether or not this answer is useful to people who come to this page. Other people have upvoted it. That is fine. This mechanism is what the whole of SO is based on. I also pointed out *why* I didn't think it was a useful answer. This is again how SO is designed.

Comment: The fact that eleven different parties have MPs in the UK would be a likely explanation for why "bipartisan" is *not* used in the UK, but not necessarily an explanation for why "cross-party" *is* used. About half of the Congresses of the US have had members of at least a third party, but the numbers of third (or fourth) party members have historically been so low (ten or fewer at a time in the last 100 years), that "bipartisan" has been accurate enough in the US for quite some time now. Ref: http://www.infoplease.com/ipa/A0774721.html

Comment: @ToddWilcox The term ***bipartisan*** is certainly used in the UK, but as a more general expression. Where a specific understanding is reached between two or more political parties the term ***cross-party*** is more likely.

Answer (score 4):

A [search](https://www.google.com/search?q=cross-party%20alliances%20in%20american%20politics&oq=cross-party%20alliances%20in%20american%20politics&aqs=chrome..69i57.5879j0j8&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8) for **cross-party alliances** shows that the term **cross-party** is widely used in American English.

P.S. You won't always find such words in a dictionary because they are formed by analogy, **cross** being a productive first element; e.g. *cross-database, cross-pollination, cross-town, cross-language, cross-connection, cross-traffic ...*

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest ***interparty***  [Ngram (AmEng)](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=interparty+alliances%2Cinterparty+alliance&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cinterparty%20alliances%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cinterparty%20alliance%3B%2Cc0)

> : between political parties.
> Origin inter- +‎ party [Your Dictionary](http://www.yourdictionary.com/interparty#wiktionary#DMr7suUAg9JFAczl.99)
>
> *Throughout the 1960s, however, Nelson Rockefeller and the state GOP
> blocked this interparty alliance, despite the objections of some
> county GOP organizations.* [New York State and the Rise of Modern Conservatism: Redrawing Party Lines](https://books.google.fr/books?id=yuGSiPe3BCUC&pg=PA185&dq=%22interparty+alliance%22&hl=pt-BR&sa=X&ved=0CE0Q6AEwBWoVChMI5fvfw9SayQIVyVcaCh3_EQ1F#v=onepage&q=%22interparty%20alliance%22&f=false)
>
> *... yet were unwilling (because of the party principle) to reach across the aisle to form an interparty coalition ...* [Fighting for the Speakership: the House and the Rise of Party Government](https://books.google.fr/books?id=YHlZCBqGvZIC&pg=PA106&lpg=PA106&dq=%22because+of+the+party+principle+to%22&source=bl&ots=B15_sZbwCz&sig=nFNEGhlpCHTbnEkNO8lrCPPJ4R4&hl=pt-BR&sa=X&ved=0CBsQ6AEwAGoVChMItqWp_oabyQIVAskaCh3EBgHG#v=onepage&q=%22because%20of%20the%20party%20principle%20to%22&f=false)

Answer (score 1):

I have heard this mostly used in the sphere of international relations, but one word you might consider is "**multipolar**".  This sense of the word is defined by [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/multi-polar) as "characterized by more than two centers of power or interest".

Answer (score 0):

American English has a phrase that refers to the act of bipartisan action, or people working with multiple parties, and that phrase is: ***Across the Aisle***.

- [Definition 1...](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/submission/6162/Reaching%20across%20the%20aisle)
- [A whole article explaining the term](http://www.wisegeek.com/what-does-across-the-aisle-mean.htm)

Comment: And as a footnote -- if a candidate can win support from voters outside his/her own political party or other group, then he/she has **"crossover appeal."**